# Como mostrar array en elemento <el-autocomplete>

Tags: vue.js

tengo el siguiente codigo para ejecutar el elemento

El codigo del elemento es el siguiente:

```
<el-autocomplete style="width:100%;"
    v-model="state"
    :fetch-suggestions="querySearch"
    @select="handleSelect"
    placeholder="Please input"
    :trigger-on-focus="false">
</el-autocomplete>
```

Mando el array de objeto (Imagen mas abajo) al loadAll el cual proceso y mando al elemento Links. 
Hasta el momento no he logrado obtener el nombre para hacer la busqueda. el cual esta en createFilter pero no me funciona. 
¿Cual es la forma correcta de recorrer ese array para que se muestre en mi elemento?

```
/* - BUSCADOR - */
        querySearch(query, cb) {
        var links = this.links;

        var results = query ? links.filter(this.createFilter(query)) : links;
        var top3 = results.slice(0, 4);//Define cuantos elementos se muestran en la lista
        console.log(JSON.stringify(top3));
        cb(top3); // number of things returned
        },
        createFilter(query) {
        return (link) => {
            return link.value.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        };

        },
        loadAll(array) {

        return array;
        },
        handleSelect(item) {
        this.label = item.value;
        //console.log(item.value);
        },
```

[image: Objeto/array]

Comment: Recuerda que el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Ya probaste con el v-for?

Comment: Acabo de escribir como lo tengo en el elemento

Comment: pero que tiene que ver esto con vue? no veo nada de vue aca... (mas alla que sea un array dentro de vue, el codigo no tiene nada de vue, es solo js..).. donde es que esta tu problema?

Comment: Son methods dentro de vue

Comment: ok ahora la pregunta va tomando forma.. como preguntaron alla arriba, probaste con un v-for sobre tu array???

Comment: El v-for se puede usar dentro del metodo?

Comment: no.. el v-for va en el elemento... es para repetir el elemento por cada item del array... tal vez necesites leer respecto a eso? que es ese elemento? se puede repetir? porque no suena a algo que genere una lista (o grilla o algo asi)...

Comment: Y otra cosa, tene en cuenta que hiciste varias preguntas en varios dias, y la mayoria no tiene votos positivos, ni respuestas aceptadas.. el sistema puede llegar a penalizarte si las preguntas son malas, bloqueandote para hacer nuevas preguntas. Tenelo en cuenta al redactar nuevas preguntas...

Comment: Por eso lo preguntaba, por que no quiero repetir el elemento, el elemento en si repite los datos dentro con los metodos que ya mostre arriba, pero al parecer mi metodo no funciona por que no lo muestra

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: Vue no funciona asi. Para evitar que vos tengas que recorrer y hacer todo ese trabajo, esta vue. Por eso no entiendo que queres hacer. Para mostrar valores de un array usas un v-for en el elemento que corresponda. Tal vez no estes explicandote bien, pero no entiendo que queres lograr con todos esos metodos. Cual es tu array ahi? ese es el que mostras en tu v-for